# "return" isn't returning the correct value from an array function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, return

I am trying to set the price of each array value by row. 
The price of each row has to be entered every time the program starts.

the program complies but the output is incorrect, here is what is displayed:

```
Please enter price for row  0 = 66

please enter row number 0

please enter seat number 0

0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14
---------------------------------------------
#  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |0
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |1
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |2
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |3
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |4
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |5
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |6
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |7
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |8
*  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  *  |9

-858993460

Press any key to continue . . .
```

what is incorrect is "-858993460", it should display 66. Someone help me

my code looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void drawgrid(int ai[10][15], int ji, int ii); // draw grid proto

int numb(int num[10], int tps)
// this function returns back the array possition 
// that matchest "tps" ' number
{
    return num[0];
}

void numbee(int nu[10])
// this function prompts the user for the price of each row
{

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            cout << " Please enter price for row  " << i << endl;
            cin >> nu[i];

        }

        return;
}

int printArray(int a[10][15],int tp,int pp)
// this function asks the user what seat to buy

{
        int num[10];
        cout << "please enter row number ";
        cin >> tp;
        cout << "please enter seat number";
        cin >> pp;
        a[tp][pp] = numb(num, tp);

        return 0;
}

int main() // this is the main
// calls numbee, drawgrid, and printArray
// sets all to 0 using memset
{  
        int n[10];
        numbee(n);
        int love;
        int a[10][15];
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        memset(a, 0, sizeof(a[10][15]) * 10 * 15); // set everything in gridto 0
        drawgrid(a, i, j);

        love = printArray(a, i, j);
        numb(n, love);

        drawgrid(a, i, j);

        cout << a[0][0];

        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;

}

void drawgrid(int ai[10][15], int ji, int ii)
// this function draws the gridd
{
        ii = 0; ji = 0;
        cout << "0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------";
        std::cout << std::endl;

        for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++)    //This loops on the rows.
        {
            for (int ji = 0; ji < 15; ji++) //This loops on the columns
            {
                if (ai[ii][ji] == 0)
                {
                    cout << "*" << "  ";
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "#" << "  ";
                }

            }
            cout << "|"  << ii;
            cout << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should tag the question with the language you're using.

Comment: `cin >> nu[i];` must be `cin >> *nu[i];`

Comment: @elvis.dukaj That's not going to compile.

Comment: thanks mod for edited, next time I will adopt your format for output. 

I added c++ to tag

uhh elvis thanks for advice but may you please elaborate

Comment: @user2808943: `memset(a, 0, sizeof(a[10][15]) * 10 * 15)` will work, but it is convoluted to the point of being almost humorous. Firstly, you can simply do `memset(a, 0, sizeof a)`. Secondly, you should avoid `memset` altogether and declare the array as `int a[10][15] = {}`, which will fill it with zeros from the start.

Comment: @AndreyT LOL, thanks for the advise on memset and the whicked advise on how to mass declare an array, talking to you sooner could have saved me from creating that franket-set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite confusing because of the naming - "numb" and "numbee" are nonsense, and the function that  asks for a seat is called "printArray", but doesn't ever print an array. You should probably work on your naming a bit.

On to the problem:

`printArray` has a local array variable, `num`.
This array is uninitialized, so can contain any random data.
You then assign the value of the first element of this array (returned from `numb(num, tp)`) to `a[tp][pp];`, and this is where the strange data is coming from.

It's difficult to advise on a remedy because it's a bit unclear what you intend for `numb` and code such as

```
love = printArray(a, i, j);
numb(n, love);
```

to accomplish.

Comment: ah I see, thank you for advise and answering question.

I've already edited the terrible and confusing names... I duuno what I was thinking

Answer (score 2):

In this function:

```
int printArray(int a[10][15],int tp,int pp) 
// this function asks the user what seat to buy
{
int num[10];
cout << "please enter row number ";
cin >> tp; 
cout << "please enter seat number";
cin >> pp; 
a[tp][pp] = numb(num, tp); 

return 0;
}
```

you delcare num[10] and you left it uninitialized. Then in this line:

```
a[tp][pp] = numb(num, tp);
```

through a function:

```
int numb(int num[10], int tps) 
// this function returns back the array possition 
// that matchest "tps" ' number
{
    return num[0];
}
```

you write uninitialized num[0] into a[0][0]. That's why you get garbage.